# Matlab, textscan: sequence of punctuation marks

Tags: matlab, delimiter, textscan

I want to split a string using 
**","**
as delimiter but I'm not able. I tried:

```
temp = textscan('the first","the second','%s',2,'Delimiter','","');
```

but the result is:

> temp{:}
>
> ans = 'the first'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
temp = textscan('the first","the second','%s',5,'Delimiter',{'","'});
```

I am unable to find the relevant part of the documentation, but with an array of chars `textscan` uses each char as an individual delimiter. Check `temp = textscan('the first","the second','%s',4,'Delimiter','","');` to se how the delimiter is interpeded in your code.

Comment: Thank you, now it is more clear.
I still appreciate any help to solve my problem, since I want to separate my strings only with "," and not with " or ,

>> temp = textscan('the first","the second','%s',5,'Delimiter',{'","'})
??? Error using ==> textscan
Delimiter must be a string.

>> temp = textscan('the first","the second','%s',4,'Delimiter','","')

temp = 

    {4x1 cell}

>> temp{:}

ans = 

    'the first'
    ''
    ''
    'the second'

Comment: @FrancescoVe: In recent versions [textscan](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#namevaluepairarguments) supports cell arrays or strings, I don't know when this was changed but what matlab version are you using?

Comment: 2008a. I cannot even use the function strsplit and I think it's time to move to a newer version :)
However I've just realized that in the meanwhile I can easily handle the splitting problem with Python.

Comment: @FrancescoVe: `regexp` might be an alternative. With only an old license available I would switch to octave which basically supports the same language. Since last update it comes with a nice UI (`--force-gui`).

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, your help was extremely useful and now I can go on with my work.